# Lstm with different input sizes for each batch (pyTorch)

Tags: pytorch

I am switching from TensorFlow to PyTorch and I having some troubles with my net.

I have made a Collator(for the DataLoader) that pads each tensor(originally sentence) in each batch into the Maslen of each batch.

so I have different input sizes per each batch.

my network consists of LSTM -> LSTM -> DENSE

my question is, how can I specify this variable input size to the LSTM?

I assume that in TensorFlow I would do Input((None,x)) bedsore the LSTM.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input size of the LSTM is not how long a sample is. So lets say you have a batch with three samples: The first one has the length of 10, the second 12 and the third 15. So what you already did is pad them all with zeros so that all three have the size 15. But the next batch may have been padded to 16. Sure.
But this 15 is not the input size of the LSTM. The input size in the size of one element of a sample in the batch. And that should always be the same.
For example when you want to classify names:
the inputs are names, for example "joe", "mark", "lucas".
But what the LSTM takes as input are the characters. So "J" then "o" so on. So as input size you have to put how many dimensions one character have.
If you use embeddings, the embedding size. When you use one-hot encoding, the vector size (probably 26). An LSTM takes iteratively the characters of the words. Not the entire word at once.

```
self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=embedding_size, ...)
```

I hope this answered your question, if not please clearify it! Good luck!

Comment: Hi, actually I did understand this by myself after I posted this question, this the way it works in every framework and I am not sure why I got confused to begin with.  but, I really appreciate your detailed answer. Thank you!